# In xamp my localhost do not open

Tags: php, localhost

I install xampp 2 years ago in window 7,i use it for 1 and half years, it was fine.Then after some time gap of 3 or 4 months i again try to use localhost it don't open.It open www.localhost.com and display error .In that time gap I install some software, but i am not sure these software harm my xampp.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Now i am not sure. I am from next pc

Comment: Yup, its probably Skype. Skype runs on port 80, just like XAMMP.

Comment: If so then how to solve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Skype installed, it must be it. 
You can disable Skype's behavior of listening to port 80 by following the instructions here:

http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-skype-from-using-opening-and-listening-on-port-80-and-443-on-local-computer/

Skype is listening to port 80 which is creating conflicts with XAMPP. Note that XAMPP is also using the same port.